# Find and Replace with QueryPath

Tags: php, querypath

I have a string assigned to a variable of $output. I want to use QueryPath to iterate through the string and add a class to each matched element.

Currently I have:

`$output = qp($output)->find('table')->addclass('table')->html();`

The only issue with this is it removes the content of $output before the first match. Is there a way of using QueryPath to find the match and then add the class while keeping the contents of $output intact?

EDIT:

```
Pseudo code:

$output = '<table class="temp"><blah></blah></table>';

Magic QueryPath

$output = '<table class="temp blah"><blah></blah></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing **html()**

```
$output = qp($output)->find('table')->addclass('table');
```

For displaying:

```
$output->writeHTML();
```

> html()::  Replaces the child content of the current element or elements in
>   an HTML document

Comment: I don't want to output the content yet, I want the change back in the original $output. I've updated my initial question.